# Excel VBA Get values of merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've found simillary question but it hasn't helped me.
I have a column with merged and non-merged cells. I'd like to get their values. I don't know how to use it:

```
Set ma = myWorkbook.Range("C2").MergeArea
sValue = ma.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value
```

Look at my code:

```
Private Function GetValueOfMergedCells(sName, iColumn)
    Set myWorkbook = Workbooks().Worksheets()

    Set c = myWorkbook.Cells.Find(What:=sName, After:=ActiveCell, LookAt _
                        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If (iColumn <> 2) Then
            '...
        Else
            Set ma = NEWDevicesWS.Range("C2").MergeArea
            MsgBox ma.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value
            GetValueOfMergedCells = ma.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value
        End If
    Else
        '...
    End If
End Function


Sub main()
    Set firstWorkbook = Workbooks().Worksheets()

    ' Get array of strings
    Dim aNames() As String
        aNames = ImportSamplesNames() 

    For i = 1 To UBound(aNames())
        firstWorkbook.Cells(3 + i, 2) = GetValueOfMergedCells(aNames(i), 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, describe what the result should be and explain HOW your code is not giving you that result. Only then can people help you in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

can't track down your code

so hope that:

`ma.Resize(1, 1).Value`

would do

Comment: or ma.Cells(1,1).Value